# How do I restrict access to my apache server to lan clients only server wide?

Tags: apache

The directive I am looking for is as follows:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.*.*
```

However, I don't know where to put this so that it will affect all sites.

**Edit**: Looking at Alvaro's link it seems `<Directory />` will just be overridden, and after trying it out niether `<Directory />` nor `<Directory ~ ".*">` work to block the default site which overrides the `Order`.

Is there a way to specify this one as higher priority?

Comment: The main configuration file is httpd.conf, don't use htaccess(toAllowOverride) if you don't need per site administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow):

> Allow Directive
>     *Description:* Controls which hosts can access an area of the server
>     *Syntax:*  Allow from all|host|env=[!]env-variable [host|env=[!]env-variable] ...
>     **Context: directory, .htaccess**
>     *Override:*    Limit
>     *Status*:  Base
>     *Module:*  mod_authz_host

So you don't have too many choices. See [`<Directory>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#directory) for further details.

Comment: I'll just add the directive to the default site and any others I may make. I'll also add it to the `phpmyadmin.conf` file

Comment: Please note that `<Directory>` does not need to go inside a `<VirtualHost>` container.